# Getting screen protection installed

Tags: word-usage

If I want to get a "screen protector" on my phone, I know it is natural to used:

> I am going to get a screen protector installed on my phone.

But if I already have it on my phone but it has cracked and I want to get a new one,  is the use of "install" still natural? Or will it be better to use "replace"?

> I have to get this guard replaced.

Or can "install" be used as well? I guess,  it won't sound natural as I already guard on my phone. Am I right?

Comment: I think for screen protectors (the flimsy plastic things?) Applied and Removed sound more natural - and replaced to remove and apply a new one

Comment: And @Smock does "put on" sound natural  as well?  "I have to put on the screen protector.

Comment: And @Smock , will applied be used as: "I have to get a screen protector applied on my phone".

Comment: And "removed" : I have to get the screen protector  removed.

Comment: *I am going to get a **new** screen protector installed on my phone.*

Comment: And @JasonBassford, , what do you think about "replace"? Does it sound natural?  And what do you think about "apply" ? "I have to get a screen cover applied". (It is the first time)  and can "applied be used instead of "replace": "I have to get a new screen protector applied ".

Comment: And @Smock , what do yoy think about my sentences?

Comment: Yeah, they seem ok to me. The only reason I wouldn't use 'install' is that it suggests (to me) using screws or nuts and bolts, or at least, something more involved than just laying a plastic sheet on the top of a phone screen. You don't 'install' a layer of paint on a wall for instance. (It's still correct to use it in this instance though).

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish You had asked about the use of *install*. I was commenting that if you use the adjective *new*, then using *install* would still sound natural. You wouldn't *have* to switch to a different verb—although doing so is an alternative. Whether you do or not is personal choice.